# Magento PWA Template Projects

Tags: pwa

It's my understanding that Magento's @magento/venia-concept package is a PWA template project.  You can use Magento's PWA template projects in an invocation of the  `buildpack` command

```
buildpack create-project /path/to/a/folder \
        --template "venia-concept"\
        --name "your-project"\
        --author "Alan Storm <astorm@alanstorm.com>"\
        --backend-url "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/"\
        --braintree-token "san...qzk" 
        --npm-client "npm"\
        --no-install
```

to setup a PWA system.

My Question: Are there other open source PWA Template projects, or is `venia-concept` the only one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further research, this `--template` option is [hard coded to only accept venia-concept](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/025cfe471c7937c5aa1cb486a1d6aa85016563c2/packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/cli/create-project.js#L114) -- this (and other research) leads me to believe that PWA Studio templates aren't really a thing (yet?) and that in practice most folks doign according to Hoyle PWA Studio are building on top of this venia-concept theme, despite it being "only a concept".